# Windows 10 can't select bluetooth headset as audio output device

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, headphones, headset

I have a Windows 10 PC and Bose Soundlink 2 headphones, that have an inbuilt mic. I have paired the two, and my headphones appear as both stereo (no mic) headphones and a mono (mic) headset. I understand why this is the case, but that is not my issue.

If I get in a Discord call for example, I can't play audio from any games or apps. Obiously, Discord uses the headset mode as input since it requires a mic, and since I can't use both modes simultaneously, it also uses the headset mode as output. Fair enough.

However, I can't select the headset mode as an output device in Windows settings. I actually have to go into control panel and set the headset device as the default device. Surely I don't have to do this each time?

Is there a way to say that by default all applications use the stereo heaphones, and then if an application is using the mono headset, switch all other applications to the mono headset as their respective output devices?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but the other way around. I have a JBL BT500 Bluetooth headset, I can use it as a headphone (stereo) just fine i.e. music and videos, though when I select the headset mode (hands free) which is mono but enables the use of the microphone (for calls in MS Teams or Skype) I cannot hear the other part but they can hear me, or I hear some robotic distorted voices from the other side.
I tried several changes in the configuration and disables the audio enhancements with the same results.